# py2exe, executable: How to pack data into single file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, py2exe

I am wondering of how to pack several files into one single windows executable file with py2exe. I could get all python files (dll's, ...) into one py2exe. But how can i copy some of my own files (i.e. images or configuration files) into my executable and load them into python with a relative path. In Example:

```
file = open("config.txt",r")
file2 = open("mysubfolder\config.txt","r")
```

Comment: @Algo I think that one is different because it is asking about the libraries, this one is about the extra data files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can embed your image files into the exe. If there is a way, I'm also interested. What I know is that you can use them from a separate folder. For this, you need to modify your setup file. Add a data path for the thing you want to load. For example, add this to your setup file:

```
import glob

data_files = [('mysubfolder', glob.glob('mysubfolder/config.txt'))]

setup(
   data_files = data_files,
   windows = [GUI2Exe_Target_1]
)
```

Of course, you can add more folders or files to data_files.
And for other configuration options in this setup file, you can refer to the py2exe official site.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. From which package do you import glob.glob?

Comment: Forgot to mention. import glob

Comment: It doesn't work. It creates the folder in my projectfolder/dist location -  not in the packed executable.

Comment: Yes, I said this in my answer. I don't know if you can embed these files into the exe. I can only put them into a separate folder.

Comment: Nevertheless: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PyQT (or PySide), it's possible to compile resource files into python modules (`.py` files). That way, you just need to `import` them to be able to use them, and py2exe will include them in the executable by default.

Look at [the PyQt4 Resource System](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/resources.html).

Comment: This is a good idea but i am not using pyqt. I  use tkinter. Nevertheless: Thankyou d´for your answer